# Setting zoom level based on geolocation accuracy in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

How can I calculate an appropriate zoom level to set in a Google Maps web application based on the accuracy value returned by HTML5 geolocation?

Essentially I want the map zoomed in far enough to show detail, but out far enough to show the area bounded by the accuracy radius (I'm drawing a circle around the centre-point to show the area that the user could be in).

I have found answers relating to using the maps API geocoding location_type but nothing relating to using the HTML5 geolocation accuracy value which is returned in metres.

I get the feeling setBounds might be one way to do it, but that involves converting meters to a new set of LatLng values which I get the feeling can be a bit vague (but maybe not so vague over the distances that the geolocator accuracy is likely to return).

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw the `Circle` and then use the `bounds` of the circle as argument for `fitBounds`

Comment: @Fat Monk   How did you apply this.

Comment: Probably not the easiest ting to explain in comments, but here goes. Create the 'locAccuracyCircle' circle with `locAccuracyCircle = new google.maps.Circle({put your circle params in here});`, then set the radius of that circle to the position accuracy that your location code gets using `locAccuracyCircle.setRadius(position.coords.accuracy);`. Finally set the map bounds with `map.fitBounds(locAccuracyCircle.getBounds());`

Answer (score 2):

This helped me

```
var zoomLevel = parseInt(Math.log2(591657550.5 / (accuracy * 45))) + 1;
```

This gives me reasonable zoom level based on accuracy. (haven't included pixel info for the calculation)